# Connect Raspberry Pi 3 to the IBM Cloud using Node-RED

Tags: raspberry-pi, ibm-cloud, iot, node-red, watson-iot

I referenced the [Configure a Raspberry Pi and connect it to Watson IoT Platform]

In that, I am using Node-RED of Raspberry Pi 3 and send the data to IBM Cloud.

I use the Function Node for transform to Watson IoT Format,
So, I write the code in function node.

```
msg.payload={'d':{'temp':msg.payload.replace("temp=","").replace("'C\n","")}}
```

However, it has the result that represent `{d:obeject}`
I want to represent `{"d":{"temp":"45.5"}}`

Did I miss something?

I attached image file.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Debug sidebar shows a structured, interactive, view of the message.

If you click on the `{d: object }` line it will expand to reveal its structure.